# Apex replay debugger

Tags: apex-replay-debugger

I am getting below error message when i try to run apex replay debugger.

command 'extension.replay-debugger.getlog filename' not found

I have installed salesforce extension pack, Salesforce CLI and created a project. I have uploaded the debug file but when i hit play button it shows the error.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, VSCode can work itself into some pretty weird states.

The typical IT support opening line, "try turning it off, and then back on again", usually works. That is to say, completely close VSCode, wait a few seconds, then open VSCode again.